# How to skip email verification of registration in spring security for grails?

Tags: grails

What is the right way to skip the send and verify email workflow in Spring security?  It's overkill for my application.

Using grails 3 and spring security plugin 2

I looked at the register controller to see if I could easily skip the step, but seems like there's a lot going on there that I don't want to muck with.

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve it ?